# Amazon s3 - browse exact directory's files within a bucket in Java

Tags: java, amazon-s3

How do I browse an exact directory say "210911" within a bucket, say "bucketName" in java?
I need to do so in order to download the files within that directory.

Comment: What do you mean by "Browse"? Are you looking for some sort of GUI, Explorer-esque interface?

Comment: Sorry, I've missed the important part. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by using the [AWS java sdk](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/)

Then you can use the [`ObjectListing`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ObjectListing.html) method with [`ListObjectsRequest`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ListObjectsRequest.html) to return all the objects in a bucket. If you specify a `prefix` value (`210911/` in your case) you can limit the results to a specific virtual folder.